# Weird results NOT IN with NULL query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, qsqlquery

Can any one explain to me why I'm getting different results:

`Table2.Table1ID nullable` field

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE
ID NOT IN (SELECT Table1ID FROM Table2)
```

no results

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE
ID NOT IN (SELECT Table1ID FROM Table2 WHERE Table1ID IS NOT NULL)
```

expected results: `Table1` items which are not related to `Table2`

SQL server version: 10.50.3720.0
OS: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1 (7601)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any of the values in the Table2 has `null` then First query gets transalted to

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE (ID <> NULL and ID <> SomeValue and...)
```

`ID<>NULL` is unkown .Hence you don't get any result

where as, in your 2nd query you are eliminating the `NULL` .Hence you don't get an unknown value .

You can also write your query using `Not Exists`

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE
NOT Exists (SELECT 1  FROM Table2 where Table1ID = ID )
```

Comment: I think those should be `and`s between alternatives in your translation. Otherwise, if there's more than one distinct value, then obviously one of `ID<>Value1` or `ID<>Value2` will always be true.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Yeah my mistake . `OR ` holds true for `In` operation

Comment: I've fixed your query, but 'NOT EXISTS' gives correct results.

Comment: Correct should be: 'SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE
NOT Exists (SELECT 1  FROM Table2 where Table1.ID = ID )'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE
ID NOT IN (SELECT ISNULL(Table1ID, ' ') FROM Table2)
```

`NOT IN` with `NULL` will end up in failing all condition!
It is same with oracle as well!

`NOT IN`... *NULL* obviousy is *hypothetical*!.. Not in nothing, literally even is a not a valid one isn't it!

`NULL` is something, like *not defined*.. So we have special functions available to handle `NULL`. Even for comparison we use `IS NULL` and *Not*  `= NULL`